# Getting an error with Groovy StubFor when I try and set property value

Tags: groovy, spock, stubbing

I have a dynamic AORule class that has a embedded DyanmicRule class instance as a delegate like this, and method on AORule that invokes an action on rule which tests to see if a dynamicExecution closure has been set before calling it:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@ActiveObject
@Slf4j
@EqualsAndHashCode
class AORule implements org.easyrules.api.Rule {

    //setup delegate dynamicRule and make it a part of this ActiveObject
    @Delegate DynamicRule rule

    AORule (name, description=null) {
        rule = new DynamicRule (name, description ?: "Basic Active Object Rule")
    }

    AORule () {
        rule = new DynamicRule ()
    }
    ....rest of class with a method like this

@ActiveMethod
void active_execute () {
    //rule.execute()

    if (rule.dynamicExecution != null) {
        log.debug "activeExec : running dynamicExecution closure "
        rule.dynamicExecute()  //should call closure, where this is defined
    }
    else {
        log.debug "activeExec : running std Execution action  "
        rule.execute()

    }

} ....
```

where the top of the DynamicRule class looks like this:

```
@InheritConstructors
@Component
@Slf4j  //use Groovy AST to get logger
@EqualsAndHashCode
class DynamicRule extends BasicRule implements org.easyrules.api.Rule {

    Closure dynamicEvaluation = null
    Closure dynamicExecution = null
    ....
```

I then try and define a simple Spock test for this and Stub the DynamicRule like so

```
def "set execution closure directly when doing an execute action " () {

    given:"setup of stub for testing "
    def mockres

    def stub =  new StubFor (DynamicRule)
    stub.demand.dynamicExecute { mockres = "did nothing" }
    stub.demand.getDynamicExecution = {true}  // pretend this has been set

   when : "execution passing closure value at same time  "

   //have to run new, actions etc in scope of class stub
   stub.use {
       def rule = new AORule ()
       rule.execute()
   }

    then : "test execute closure ran as expected "
    mockres == "did nothing"

}
```

In this test - tried to set up the Stub demand for `getDynamicExecution` property (a closure) to return true, and another demand to stub the method dynamicExecution to set the `def mockres` result. I then assert that's some value

However this gives me an error like this:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: getDynamicExecution for class: groovy.mock.interceptor.Demand

    at org.easyrules.spring.AORuleSpecTest.set execution closure directly when doing an execute action (AORuleSpecTest.groovy:91)
```

How do I set the expected result of a mocked property access in a class.  I thought setting the the Stub demand expectation for `getPropertyName = {some value}` would do the trick.  What am I doing wrong?

### Post Script

I tried to setup a dumbed down version of testing approach I have used like this

```
class DummyStubSpecTest extends Specification {

    def "test z stub " () {

        def res

        given :

            def zstub = new StubFor (Zthing.class)
            zstub.demand.execute {res = "hello"}
            zstub.demand.getVar {false}


        when :
            zstub.use {
                def a = new Athing()
                a.z.execute()
            }

        then :
            res == "hello"
    }

    def "test Athing stub " () {

        def res

        given :
        def astub = new StubFor (Athing.class)
        astub.demand.doit {res = "hello"}

        when :
        astub.use {
            def a = new Athing ()
            a.doit()
        }

        then :
        res == "hello"
    }
}
```

and a Spock test like this:

```
def "test z stub " () {

    def res

    given :

        def zstub = new StubFor (Zthing.class)
        zstub.demand.execute {res = "hello"}
        zstub.demand.getVar {false}


    when :
        zstub.use {
            def a = new Athing()
            a.z.execute()
        }

    then :
        res == "hello"
}
```

and this does work - so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong in previous example.

### Second postscript

One suggestion was that I should use GroovyMock to run the test with, so I tried this

```
def "set execution closure using GroovyMock to  Stub to  execute action " () {

    given:"setup of stub for testing "
    def mockres

    GroovyMock (DynamicRule, global:true)
    DynamicRule.dynamicExecute() >> {mockres = "did nothing"}

    when : "execution passing closure value at same time  "

    //have to run new, actions etc in scope of class stub

        def rule = new AORule ()
        rule.execute()

    then : "test execute closure ran as expected "
    mockres == "did nothing"

}
```

However when I run this the assertion fails again - mockres is not being set, when the execute() triggers the internal `DynamicRule.dynamicExecute()` method on my mocked object.

### Third Postcript

I have tried again -  first a 'dummy pair of classes and dummy test to try groovyMocks - and this works.  Here are my eponymous Athing and Zthing

```
//define subject under test
class Athing {
    def z = new Zthing()
    def res

    def doit() {
        z.greet()
        res = z.execute()
    }
}

//dependency to be stubbed
class Zthing {
    def var = true

    def execute() {if (var) println "its true" else  println "its false"; var}

    def greet() { println "hello"}
}
```

here is the test i defined

```
class DummyStubSpecTest extends Specification {

def "test z with GroovyMock " () {

    given:
    def a = new Athing()
    def res

    def mock = GroovyMock (Zthing) {  //, global:true
        1*execute() >> {println "stub called"; res=true}
    }

   a.z = mock

    when:
    a.doit()

    then:
    res == true

}
```

I created the mock and set the interaction expectation (1*) and stubbed response, which sets my external `res` to some string so I can test for that.

Because the instance of 'a' has an embedded 'z' instance, I overwrite the `a.z` reference to point to the mock.  I then call the SUT in the when clause, and check that `res` has been set.  This does work.

However my real class/test still refuse to work. So my AORule has a DynamicRule reference

```
class AORule implements org.easyrules.api.Rule {

//setup delegate dynamicRule and make it a part of this ActiveObject
@Delegate DynamicRule rule

AORule (name, description=null) {
    rule = new DynamicRule (name, description ?: "Basic Active Object Rule")
}

AORule () {
    rule = new DynamicRule ()
} ....
```

where the execute method in AORule look like this

```
void execute () {
    active_execute()
}

/**
 * Active method manages async action through object inside through hidden actor.
 * variable 'rule' is the variable we are protecting.  Runs either any dynmicExecution closure
 * where defined or just runs the standard class execute method
 *
 * @return void
 */
@ActiveMethod
void active_execute () {
    //rule.execute()

    if (rule.dynamicExecution != null) {
        log.debug "activeExec : running dynamicExecution closure "
        rule.dynamicExecute()  //should call closure, where this is defined
    }
    else {
        log.debug "activeExec : running std Execution action  "
        rule.execute()

    }

}  ....
```

My test for this looks like this:

```
def "set execution closure using GroovyMock to  Stub out  dynamicExecute action " () {

    given:"setup of stub for testing "
    def mockres

    def mock = GroovyMock (DynamicRule) {  //, global:true
        1*dynamicExecute() >> {-> println "stub called"; mockres = "did nothing" }
        0*execute()
    }
    aorule.rule = mock

    when : "execution passing closure value at same time  "

    //have to run new, actions etc in scope of class stub

        //def rule = new AORule ()
        aorule.setDynamicExecution {println "hi"}
        aorule.execute()

    then : "test execute closure ran as expected "
    mockres == "did nothing"

}
```

The test doesn't work correctly - the assertion shows `mockres` to be null (not being set).

I thought it might be because the activeEvaluate is internally checking on activeEvaluation closure is set, so I tried changing the GroovyMock to a GroovySpy (so that my `aorule.setDynamicExecution` call should work), and it still fails.

I can't seem to see where I am going here. My simple example seems to work and my real test doesn't.

I also tried brute force and used metaClass to hack an execute closure to set mockres, and that didn't get called either.

Comment: spotted first error the `stub.demand.getDynamicExecution = {true}` should read `stub.demand.getDynamicExecution {true}` (remove the equals - however when i do this i get another error which reads (this is my assertion failure in the when clause ) `Condition not satisfied:

mockres == "did nothing"` so the dynamicExecute  stub doesnt appear to have run

Comment: You are using Spock, why don't you use `GroovyMock` which is more integrated ?

Comment: i was trying to use spock as i liked the given/when/then format - but i wanted to stub the callborator (`DynamicRule rule` - here inside AORule )  However even after correcting my mistake setting up the demad closure - when i run it my assertion fails - so the execute() stub is not doing what i expected and setting the result so i can test the value in the where clause

Comment: Spock support stubs, it's just not "StubFor", it's "GroovyMock".

Comment: ok i tried that and result is still not been set, and assertion still fails - i changed my given: clause like this `GroovyMock (DynamicRule, global:true)
        DynamicRule.dynamicExecute() >> {mockres = "did nothing"}
`  and then ran the `rule.execute` in my when: clause (this is the SUT) and then run the assertion in the then: clause - my `mockres` is not being set, i've just revised the original question with second postcript so you can see the coded test i have just added - assming i have understood how GroovyMock should work.

Comment: I've read the spocks GroovyMock/stub/spy pages.  and tried to do what i think it tells me i should - it works for dumb ass example - but not my real class/test.  see postcript 3 addition to original question.  Stuck

Comment: Would you mind mentioning the Maven coordinates or your rule engine library and maybe other dependencies, if any? I think it will be easier to reproduce your problem than to just read and speculate about the code. Please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and why it helps to get better answers.

Comment: When I tried to use your incoherent code snippets without class and package names and without imports, I got as far as being able to compile it with the `org.easyrules:easyrules-core:2.5.0` dependency after commenting out `@ActiveMethod`. But your test does not make any sense to me in any version you provided because you seem to be testing for a result of a method which does not have any result because it returns `void`. So please, please edit your question in order to be an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. something I can copy, compile and run. This is just chaotic.